# Lotus Notes - Refresh form after button click

Tags: button, refresh, lotus-notes

I have a form which have a section. This section have a hide-when formula

`@If(flag = " 1 ";@False;@True)`

I created a button which has the formula: `@Setfield("flag";"1")` . But, the section doesn't appear immediately, it seems it needs a Refresh. I put right after `@Command([ViewRefreshFields])` but I have the following message:

`" .... not found in name & address book or any domino directory "`.

The button doesn't have `Refresh fields on keyword changes`, like other design items.

Please help, I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Error Message comes from a property of one of your name- fields. This property is on the second tab and sais "Look up addresses on document refresh". It has nothing to do with you button and will most probably also appear when you simply press F9...

Comment: Thanks for your answer.So, when the form it composed, I press F9 then I get no messages. When i select from a combobox ( this combobox has no checkmark on that property from the 2nd tab ) a value, then I get a message-error with the name of the value not found in name & adress .... So, it means there is another field ( combobox / checkbox / etc. ) that could have this property checked ?

Comment: Yes indeed, I have 2 name-fields, but they don't have checked the property "Look up addreses on document refresh". At choices there is: Use Adress dialog for choices and the property "Look up names as each character is entered" is marked.

Comment: I just checked: The Property "Look up Addresses on document refresh" is not restricted to name- fields. That means: this option is set in ANY field on your form... and the value you enter there cannot be found anywhere...